# v0.8 LinkToken.sol error. ParserError: not found: File not found?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, python

I get these version import errors when I tried to execute "brownie run scripts/deploy_lottery.py" I'm learning blockchain with the help of freecodecamp.org's youtube video.

it's working fine with the older version.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.4/ERC677Token.sol";
import {StandardToken as linkStandardToken} from 
"@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.4/vendor/StandardToken.sol";
```

but I'm using this new version,

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.11;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ERC677Token.sol";
import {StandardToken as linkStandardToken} from 
"@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vendor/StandardToken.sol";

contract LinkToken is linkStandardToken, ERC677Token {
    uint256 public constant totalSupply = 10**27;
    string public constant name = "ChainLink Token";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
    string public constant symbol = "LINK";

    function LinkToken() public {
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    }........
  # REST OF THE CODE...
```

This is the error I'm getting on my terminal....--> brownie run scripts/deploy_lottery.py
Brownie v1.16.4 - Python development framework for Ethereum

```
New compatible solc version available: 0.8.11
Compiling contracts...
  Solc version: 0.8.11
  Optimizer: Enabled  Runs: 200
  EVM Version: Istanbul
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

ParserError: Source"/Users/mohameduzair/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-       mix@2.3.0/contracts/src/v0.8/ERC677Token.sol" not found: File not found.
 --> contracts/test/LinkToken.sol:4:1:
  |
4 | import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ERC677Token.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


ParserError: Source"/Users/mohameduzair/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-mix@2.3.0/contracts/src/v0.8/vendor/StandardToken.sol" not found: File not found.
 --> contracts/test/LinkToken.sol:5:1:
  |
5 | import {StandardToken as linkStandardToken} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vendor/StandardToken.sol"; ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So, how can I fix this issue, please?
these are the images...
[image: this is the LinkToken.sol file and errors]
[image: this is the brownie-config.yaml file]

Answer (score 0):

LinkToken is available for v0.4 only. Change directory address to `@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.4/LinkToken`